# Make one object avoid another object

Tags: java

Im making a 2D game where the red circles (enemies) will chase the player and the blue circles (allies). Each of these classes extend my class called Entity, and i have all of the Entities that I create in an ArrayList called entities. I wanted the blue circles to avoid the enemies where possible... Here is some code that I tried, that I thought would work:

```
public void runAwayFrom(Entity e){
    double xpos = e.getX();
    double ypos = e.getY();
    double xd = xpos - x;
    double yd = y - ypos;
    double d = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xd,2))+(Math.pow(yd,2)));

    double xrate = xd/400;
    double yrate = yd/400;
    x -= xrate*speed;
    y -= yrate*speed;
}
```

This method is called in my tick method like so:

```
public void tick(int i){
    if(isControlled()){

    }else{
        Enemy e = (Enemy)getNearestEnemy();
        runAwayFrom(e);
    }
}
```

And here is the getNearestEnemy method just incase:

```
public double getDistance(Entity target) {
   return Math.hypot(target.getX() - getX(), target.getY() - getY());
}

public Entity getNearestEnemy() {
    double nearestdist = 50000;
    Entity nearestent = null;
    for(Entity e : w.getObjectsOfClassInWorld(Enemy.class)){
        double dist = getDistance(e);
        if(dist < nearestdist){
            nearestdist = dist;
            nearestent = e;
        }
    }
    return nearestent;
}
```

So all that seems to happen is the blue circles move towards the enemies and then it sometimes crashes... I wanted to have it so they moved at the same speed (as in, a constant speed, not variable) and simply try to avoid going near the enemies, but I have clearly failed so how would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried running this with a single enemy? How does it behave?

Comment: It works better with only one enemy, but the blue circle guy slows down as the enemy gets closer

Comment: Is there any reason why you calculate `xd` and `yd` in the opposite signs?

Comment: That sounds ok to me, since in the `runAwayFrom` the values you're subtracting from `x` and `y`depend on the distance from the entity it's running from, your `yd` and `xd` variables. If you want your blue circle to run away at constant speed the position of the entity it's running from should only affect the direction of the movement, not its distance.

Comment: Well Dolda2000 just pointed out one error thx

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments, it seems the result of having the blue circles slow down as they get closer to the enemies is unintentional. If you want to avoid this, you need to calculate your `xrate` and `yrate` as dimensionless proportions to the total distance instead of using the absolute values of `xd` and `yd`:

```
double xrate = xd / d;
double yrate = yd / d;
```

Also, I suspect that the calculation of `yd` in the inverse sign is unintentional, as it will cause the allies to move closer to the enemies along the Y axis, if not along the X axis.